# Using Scrollspy with 2 Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to use Scrollspy from Bootstrap. The instruction seems to be simple. However I am having problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/2cerpabp/

And since Stackoverflow requires it, here's the "Code":

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="HeaderContent col-md-12" style="height:300px;">
Header
</div>
<hr>

<!-- Left Side-->
<div class="col-xs-6">
Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
</div>

<!-- Right Side -->

<div class="col-xs-6" style="height:400px;overflow:auto;" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-sidebar">
    <div style="width:40px;position:fixed;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav-sidebar">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#nav-side-view-history"><i
                class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#nav-side-view-addresses"><i
                class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#nav-side-view-map"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#nav-side-view-info"><i
                class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#nav-side-view-texts"><i
                class="fa fa-align-left"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="nav-side-view-history">
            <h4>
                History
            </h4>
            <p>History Text</p>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <div id="nav-side-view-map">
            <h4>
                Map
            </h4>
            <p>Map</p>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <div id="nav-side-view-addresses">
            <h4>
                Addresses
            </h4>
            <p>Addresses</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="nav-side-view-info">
            <h4>Info</h4>
            <p>Info/p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="nav-side-view-texts">
            <h4>Texts</h4>
            <p>Texts</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div style="height:400px;">

    </div>

</div>
```

See the problem is I only want a small div to use the Scrollspy on the right side. However since my header takes up so much space and I have some content on the left, i get scrollbar also for my body.

Now when I for example hit on the "Map"-Icon it should scroll to the Map section. It does it, but by also scrolling the whole page.

I only want the div with the information to do that. Additionally it won't highlight the right icon, after it has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Body tag having a scrollbar can be hidden using simple CSS

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Secondly, Highlighting the right icon after it has been clicked is just a matter of setting a class (active) in the li tag. This can be achieved using jQuery as follows.

```
$('#nav-sidebar li').click(function() {
  $('#nav-sidebar li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

You can find the full solution on the link below

https://jsfiddle.net/YasirKamdar/vmhskqj4/

Comment: Thanks. However I need the both scrollbars. In my real example it makes more sense. Concerning the click, why doesn't Bootstrap does this? I did it as said in the Tutorial, where they don't do that, and it just works.

Comment: Found your issue, On the console it shows an exception "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6" This can be because of the order in which you have your external reference or a non compatible jQuery version. By just switching the order of the reference and using the jQuery version in the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ you should be able to make it work

Comment: Fixed it: https://jsfiddle.net/2cerpabp/1/  but still it doesn't do what I want. Also it would be strange, since on my regular project I didnt get the error.

Comment: see this link, I was able to fix the active issue be restructuring the HTML, but for some reason the CSS of active class wasn't applying so add that in CSS and all works fine https://jsfiddle.net/YasirKamdar/2cerpabp/6/

Comment: That's funny. But still i get the issue that the whole page scrolls. I only want the small div on the right to do that

Comment: That I don’t think can be achieved using bootstrap scrollspy as all the samples on bootstrap component page also scroll the page untill the component reaches the top of the screen, you need to have a custom implementation to achieve what your looking for.